Jenkins when branch merged or deleted
we are using jenkins declarative pipeline with multi branches the repo hosted on bitbucket with webhooks configured on merged , push and approved  ,
as we have  many features branches  so the builds are generated based on this like creating the dns zones configuring the db connection etc , and everything work like charm the problem is when the branch closed/merged jenkins become un-aware of that so the housekeeping jobs not triggered  tried to google things how to make jenkins aware of those branches being closed/deleted or merged on same pipeline with no luck any hints or thoughts on this are  appreciated
tried work around for job to watch the branches and fire the housekeeping jobs  but things got messy so fast and become so complex

Multi-branch pipelines only trigger when a branch receives a commit, and doesn't notice when the branch is merged or deleted. You could take a look at the MultiBranch Action Triggers plugin that might do what you want. Since you're on Bitbucket, consider using webhooks. Look at this answer for more.
You could also handle this whole thing manually, where you run a build periodically that lists down all the branches that exist in your repo. The next time the build runs it lists down the branches again and also checks against the previous list from the earlier run to see if any branches have been deleted. If so, you could get it to trigger a job that does the housekeeping.

Multibranch config runs pipelines from branches. If your branch is deleted, which pipeline do you expect Jenkins to run?
Make a cleanup job that is triggered by repo:push with push.changes.closed set to true (from here). A periodic job would make sense too for any missed web hooks.

not using that approach as we are using  different approach single pipeline for different branches/tags using the following plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/remote-file , and as i said before already have separate job to do that , but things are not the cleanest way as is , thanks for the info
